# Using two for loops to find duplicates

Tags: typescript, for-loop, if-statement

This is my function to enable button if conditions are met and function return true. I've added additional for loop to find duplicates and now it doesn't work right. Please advise where did I make a mistake?

```
 enabled(): boolean {
    for (let i: number = 0; i < this.entries.length; ++i) {
      let strText: string = this.entries[i].textN;
      let strValue: number = this.entries[i].valueN;

      if (strText.includes('=') || strText.includes(',')) {
        return false;
      }

      if (strText == null || strText == undefined || strText == '') {
        return false;
      }

      if (!strValue || strValue % 1 !== 0) {
        return false;
      }

      for (let j = i + 1; j < this.entries.length; ++j) {
        if (strValue[i] === strValue[j]) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does "it doesn't work right" mean?

Comment: Hi urasavidi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please add the inputs and the expected results to the question. Have a look at [ask].

Comment: I have array of objects and this objects have text(strText) elements and numbers(strValue). I just need a condition that will compare all numbers (strValue) and if there will be any duplicates it will return false, so whole function will return true and I will use it to disable my submit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be here:

```
for (let j = i + 1; j < this.entries.length; ++j) {
    if (strValue[i] === strValue[j]) {
      return false;
    }
}
```

I think what you want is:

```
for (let j = i + 1; j < this.entries.length; ++j) {
    if (this.entries[i].textN === this.entries[j].textN) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

strValue[i] isn't meant to be compared to strValue[j]

Comment: thank you for working on this Steve. I have array of objects and this objects have text(strText) elements and numbers(strValue). I just need a condition that will compare all numbers (strValue) and if there will be any duplicates it will return false, so whole function will return true and I will use it to disable my submit button

Comment: So surely this: strValue[i] === strValue[j] isn't what you want in the loop. You want to test the current textN against all other textN for duplication so  you'd need this: this.entries[i].textN === this.entries[j].textN

Comment: Wow that's smart, thank you sir!
You helped me a lot.